# GHOST THEME DEVELOPMENT - Using gulp and zipping theme

Tags: node.js, gulp, zip, ghost-blog

I am having trouble turning my ghost theme built using the local development on windows into a zip file which I can then upload to my production server.

There are very limited guides on this topic, any helps/walkthrough this process would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Camden

Answer (score 0):

You might have better luck manually zipping your theme up than using the gulp command that's built into some of the themes. Windows appears to have issues when compressing folders into zip files using the gulp command